# Use csv file with multiple newline characters in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, newline

I'm trying to import a csv file which has `#` as delimiter and `\r\n` as line break. Inside one column there is data which also has newline in it but `\n`.

I'm able to read one line after another without problems but using the csv lib (Python 3) I've got stuck.
The below example throws a

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Is it possible to use the csv lib with multiple newline characters?

Thanks!

```
import csv

with open('../database.csv', newline='\r\n') as csvfile:
    file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='#', quotechar='"')    
    for row in file:
        print(row[3])
```

database.csv:

```
2202187#"645cc14115dbfcc4defb916280e8b3a1"#"cd2d3e434fb587db2e5c2134740b8192"#"{  
    Age = 22;  
    Salary = 242;  
}
```

Comment: so all you want is to ignore linebreaks within fields of format `{...\n ....\n ... }` ?

Comment: Hm yes, if the linebreaks in column 3 would disappear this should work. I'm not sure if a string replacement might work as the database is about 12 GB in size and how to replace only the \n in the column 3?

Comment: the most simple workaround is to replace/remove linebreaks within fields `{ ... }`. Then, work with flat csv without problems

Comment: I agree but this seems quite impossible if I do not have access to the column using the csv lib. The only way would be opening the file, read line by line, manually searching for last column, creating substring, replacing inside the substring and merge it to the original line. But this seems quite complex for a simple workaround

Comment: well, I would have done it in a few minutes in Linux command-line. There's always a choice

Comment: Even with cut and sed: how to only replace the \n in the specific column?

Comment: Are you sure your "database.csv" has the newlines encoded consistently? I'm having no problem reading the file using `\r\n` as the newline and `\n` inside of the `{ ... }` column. Reversing the newlines works too.

Comment: Did you successfully used the data in csv.reader? Using just open('database.csv, newline='\r\n') and then iterate over it works fine but using the csv lib failes

Comment: @MikeNathas Yes, I used your code on Python 3.6, and a hex editor to get the line endings right for database.csv because they don't copy and paste well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. According to [Python 3.5.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.5.4/library/functions.html#open), with `newline=None`, common line endings like `'\r\n'` ar replaced by `'\n'`.

```
import csv

with open('../database.csv', newline=None) as csvfile:
    file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='#', quotechar='"')    
    for row in file:
        print(row[3])
```

I've replaced `newline='\r\n'` by `newline=None`.
You also could use the `'rU'` modifier but it is deprecated.

```
...
with open('../database.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
...
```